# Displaying react javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, display

I have this function that sets the date from two weeks ago:

```
 dateTwoWeeksAgo: function(){
    var twoWeeksAgo = new Date().toDateString();
    this.setState({twoWeeksAgo: twoWeeksAgo});
  },
```

I have this code that calls this function. But it is not working. how do I display a variable I am setting the state of or returning from a function?

```
<h2 className="headings" id="commitTotal"> Commits since {this.dateTwoWeeksAgo} : {this.state.commits.length} </h2>
```

Comment: Could you share full component code?

Comment: what else would you like to see? Pasting the whole file would be too big. Surely there is a simple way to display the data after I've set the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**: In order to display the value of `twoWeeksAgo` held on you state you can:

```
<h2 className="headings" id="commitTotal"> Commits since {this.state.twoWeeksAgo} : {this.state.commits.length} </h2>
```

The actual method which updates your state - `dateTwoWeeksAgo()` - could be called for example in the `componendDidMount` lifefycle method. 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/LRAmBr

**Option 2**: Alternatively, you can just call a method which returns the required date like so (http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/NRzzaX),

```
const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      commits: ['One', 'Two']
    };
  },

  dateTwoWeeksAgo: function() {
    return new Date().toDateString();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="headings" id="commitTotal"> Commits since {this.dateTwoWeeksAgo()} : {this.state.commits.length} </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
})
```

Code option 1:

```
const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      twoWeeksAgo: null,
      commits: ['One', 'Two']
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.dateTwoWeeksAgo();
  },

  dateTwoWeeksAgo: function() {
    var twoWeeksAgo = new Date().toDateString();
    this.setState({twoWeeksAgo: twoWeeksAgo});
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="headings" id="commitTotal"> Commits since {this.state.twoWeeksAgo} : {this.state.commits.length} </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: it isn't working for some reason. must I have it inside `didMount?`

Comment: cool, this works. What is important about component did mount then?

Comment: componentDidMount() is an in-built React 'lifecycle method'. It is invoked once by the React just after your component has been rendered. This is the place for example to make AJAX calls. I've just added a link to React docs where you can learn more about it. Would you like me to add anything to the above or does it answer your question?

Comment: I've just added a second solution for your problem. Please check out the codepen link for option 2. This avoids using state to keep the date.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<h2 className="headings" id="commitTotal"> Commits since {this.state.dateTwoWeeksAgo} : {this.state.commits.length} </h2>
```

The difference is `this.state.dateTwoWeeksAgo`

Comment: this is what I thought as well but it just is returning blank with no errors

Answer (score 0):

For your example of code I suggest this approach

```
 dateTwoWeeksAgo: function(){
    return new Date().toDateString();
  },

<h2 className="headings" id="commitTotal"> Commits since {this.dateTwoWeeksAgo()} : {this.state.commits.length} </h2>
```

if you really want to use state you need to change `{this.dateTwoWeeksAgo} to {this.state.dateTwoWeeksAgo}`

Comment: this is what I thought as well but it just is returning blank with no errors